# MahApps - Alterar ícones para um formato PNG desejado

Tags: c#, wpf

Encontrei um projeto WPF na web muito bacana. Ele utiliza um framework chamado MahApps. No menu Hamburger há alguns ícones que utilizam imagens de uma pacote do próprio Mahapps. Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de eu alterar o bloco e configurar de maneira que eu consiga informar uma imagem png em vez de usar uma do pacote do mahapps. Alguém saberia como?

```
using System;
using MahApps.Metro.IconPacks;

namespace MahAppsMetroHamburgerMenuNavigation.ViewModels
{
    internal class ShellViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            // Build the menus
            this.Menu.Add(new MenuItem() { Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() { Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Bug }, Text = "Bugs", NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/BugsPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});
            this.Menu.Add(new MenuItem() {Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() {Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.UserOutline}, Text = "User", NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/UserPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});
            this.Menu.Add(new MenuItem() {Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() {Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Coffee}, Text = "Break", NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/BreakPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});
            this.Menu.Add(new MenuItem() {Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() {Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.FontAwesome}, Text = "Awesome", NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/AwesomePage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});

            this.OptionsMenu.Add(new MenuItem() {Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() {Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Cogs}, Text = "Settings", NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/SettingsPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});
            this.OptionsMenu.Add(new MenuItem() {Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() {Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.InfoCircle}, Text = "About", NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/AboutPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)});
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse `PackIconFontAwesomeKind`, podes adicionar essa tua imagem lá nele, mas deve ter algum outro lugar ligando o que tu cria no `PackIconFontAwesomeKind` com o local físico da imagem, podes criar por exemplo: `PackIconFontAwesomeKind.MinhaImagem`

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Rafael :)